# UISearchController in tableHeaderView crashes due to AutoLayout

Tags: ios

I'm learning about UISearchController and a lot of the examples show that you create a UISearchController and put the searchController.searchBar in the tableHeaderView.  So I did that in my code and it looks ok, until I start typing, and go to a detail view, and then back and it crashes with the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x61000007a780 "UIView:0x7f89e7f2df20.top"> and <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x608000075dc0 "UINavigationBar:0x7f89e7c0cc10.bottom"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'
```

The code I have for creating the UISearchController looks like:

```
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar // remove and it works
```

If I remove that last line `tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar` I do not get any crashes.  Is there something that needs to be done in order to get this working?  I included an animated gif to show it failing.

[image]

Comment: First of all **How you can assign UISearchBar to UIView??**

Comment: @agent_stack that's what tutorials like this say: https://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial

Comment: Now can't say any thing :/ . But try once by taking uiview & check either it is still cashing or not.